# how to read contents of html file from server in ios

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I have a json stored inside my an html file.I am trying to read the contents of html file but the contents are displaying blank.
This is my code:

```
 NSString* urlString = @"http://www.test.com/test.html";

  NSURL* myURL =
      [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                          NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  NSString* string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:nil];

//the json located at html file is 
{"ver":"4","release":"0","opt":"4"}
```

but my string is returning nil.
Thanks

Comment: I suppose that the content encoding is not UTF8. Try with NSASCIIStringEncoding. I move my suggestion to the comment. See Neeku's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you have valid UTF8 data, using something like this:

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;
    NSString *receivedData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&encoding error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"Encoding %d",encoding);
```

These are the available encodings:

```
enum {
    NSASCIIStringEncoding = 1,      /* 0..127 only */
    NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding = 2,
    NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding = 3,
    NSUTF8StringEncoding = 4,       //**THIS IS FOR UTF8.**
    NSISOLatin1StringEncoding = 5,
    NSSymbolStringEncoding = 6,
    NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding = 7,
    NSShiftJISStringEncoding = 8,          /* kCFStringEncodingDOSJapanese */
    NSISOLatin2StringEncoding = 9,
    NSUnicodeStringEncoding = 10,
    NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding = 11,    /* Cyrillic; same as AdobeStandardCyrillic */
    NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding = 12,    /* WinLatin1 */
    NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding = 13,    /* Greek */
    NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding = 14,    /* Turkish */
    NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding = 15,    /* WinLatin2 */
    NSISO2022JPStringEncoding = 21,        /* ISO 2022 Japanese encoding for e-mail */
    NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding = 30,

    NSUTF16StringEncoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding,      /* An alias for NSUnicodeStringEncoding */

    NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x90000100,          /* NSUTF16StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
    NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x94000100,       /* NSUTF16StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */

    NSUTF32StringEncoding = 0x8c000100,                   
    NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x98000100,          /* NSUTF32StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
    NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x9c000100        /* NSUTF32StringEncoding encoding with explicit endianness specified */
};
typedef NSUInteger NSStringEncoding;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify below line `encoding to NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy`

```
NSString* string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL
                                              encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                                                 error:nil];
```